# MySQL SSL Setup

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, ssl

I am using the [MySQL 5.7 SSL Setup Guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-encrypted-connections.html) (combined with a few other guides on the website + google searches).

I have a replica and source working, I am now trying to configure SSL.

My understanding is that MySQL generates the certs we need on startup so I am attempting to use those. I also tried to use the certbot certs I have setup for my domains but those failed (is it possible to use certbot/letsencrypt certs here?). I am just trying to get any SSL connection at this point.

I have my config files setup like so (I've tried a number of configs now)

```
# This is in the source
[mysqld]
ssl_ca=/var/lib/mysql/ca.pem
ssl_cert=/var/lib/mysql/server-cert.pem
ssl_key=/var/lib/mysql/server-key.pem
require_secure_transport=ON

# This is in the replica
[client]
ssl-ca=/var/lib/mysql/ca.pem
ssl-cert=/var/lib/mysql/client-cert.pem
ssl-key=/var/lib/mysql/client-key.pem
```

On the replica if I do `mysql -u root -p` I get this error: `ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths failed`

Looking through the logs on my replica I see that the connection to the source is failing with error code 3159.

Running `mysql > status;` on source I see that SSL is not in use.

Comment: Can you connect using other mysql user from client/replica ? Can you provide output of ```show global variables``` ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using a combo of [Digital Ocean Guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssl-tls-for-mysql-on-ubuntu-18-04) and [MySQL Guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-solutions-encrypted-connections.html)

On source my.cnf I set `require_secure_transport=ON` and I removed the path to certs.

On Replicas I had to `CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_SSL=1;` and I removed the path to certs.

Digital Ocean Guide has good troubleshooting steps.